# Calling Stored Procedures from VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone please help me on the following:

I have created a SQL Server stored procedure as follows:

```
create procedure prcGet_sub_menu_list
     @sub_menu     char(5)
as
begin
     select
          'menu_code'     =     menu_code
          'menu_name'     =     menu_name
     from sub_menu_master
     where menu_code      =     @sub_menu
end
return
```

Now i am calling this procedure from VB.NET, but i get an error like 'Stored procedure prcGet_sub_menu_list expects parameter @sub_menu which was not supplied'. Please help me on the same. The code which i have in VB.NET is as follows:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Dim sqlConn as New SqlClient.SqlConnection
sqlConn.ConnectionString = "........"
sqlConn.Open()

Dim menuCode as string
menuCode = cboDetails.selectedItem

Dim sqlCmd as New SqlCommand
sqlCmd.Connection = Connection.sqlConn
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
sqlCmd.CommandText = "prcGet_sub_menu_list"
sqlCmd.Parameter.Add("menuCode", SqlDbType.Char)

Dim sqlDA as New SqlDataAdapter()
sqlDA.SelectCommand = sqlCmd
Dim sqlDT as New DataTable
sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT)
```

This is the code that i have written and it gives me the error:
'Stored procedure prcGet_sub_menu_list expects parameter @sub_menu which was not supplied'.

Please give me some help on the same.

Regards,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the same parameter name and type like in your stored procedure.

```
  sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@sub_menu", SqlDbType.Char, 5)).Value = "Joe"
```

Geetha.

Comment: Dear Geetha, Thanks a lot for the reply. I tried the same, and it works, but instead of the value "Joe" which you have given, when i pass a variable there, it does not work and gives me an error. I have given the statement like sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@menu_code", SqlDbType.Char, 5)).Value = menuCode. Please help on the same.

Comment: Procedure or Function 'prc_test' expects parameter '@menu_code', which was not supplied. This is the error code. I dont get this error when i pass the value as .value = "MENU1" and it works fine by giving me the correct output, but not when i pass a variable. Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is having a value. Dont have any idea as to why this sort of an error is getting displayed.

Comment: Try it by changing the datatype in stored procedure and in sqldbtype as varchar/nvarchar.

Comment: Dear Geetha, sorry, the variable was not having a value and that was the reason for the error. Now it is working fine and thanks a lot for the help and support given.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and where will i mark that. Please do let me know that.

Answer (score 1):

As the message implies, you should add a parameter named "sub_menu" in the same way as you're adding the "menuCode" parameter. You should probably also give it a value:

```
sqlCmd.Parameter.Add("sub_menu", SqlDbType.Char).Value = "Blah"
```

(Of course, I don't know what the correct type is, so Char is just an example.)

Comment: Dear Evgeny, Thanks for the reply. I tried the same, and it works when a value is given at the end like .value = "MENU1", but when i pass a variable there, it does not work and gives me an error. I have given the statement like sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@menu_code", SqlDbType.Char, 5)).Value = menuCode. Please help on the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct parameter name

Something like

```
sqlCmd.Parameter.Add("@sub_menu", SqlDbType.Char)
```

And assign it a value

Something like

```
sqlCmd.Parameters("@sub_menu").Value = val
```

Have a look at [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

and maybe [Lesson 07: Using Stored Procedures](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A couple things. Parameter should be Parameters. Also sqlCmd.Parameters.Add is deprecated so use sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue:

sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("menuCode", menuCode)